# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Учусь писать ajax код через js, после нескольких монипуляций выползла следующия ошибка - SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<';
В ошибке показывает html файл -  - часть. В интернете смотрел, но решения не нашел, возможно вместо js подключается html файл, как исправить не знаю.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector("#send").onclick = function() {
    ajaxPost('app.php','a=b', function(data) {
      document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = data;
      // console.log(data);
    });
  };

  function ajaxPost(url,params, callback) {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        callback(request.responseText);
      }

    };
    request.open('POST',url);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send(params);
  }

};
```

```css
<?php  /* app.php */

$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$dt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

if ($email == '' || $phone == '' || $name == '') {
    echo "Заполните все поля";
}
elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "Введите корректный адрес эл. почты";
}
else {
    file_put_contents('apps.txt', '$dt $email $phone $name \n', FILE_APPEND);
    echo '1';
}

<?php /* ip.php */
  echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- index.html -->
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ajax</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" id="shop_id" value="Показать мой IP">
    <div id="myip"></div>
    <form>
      Email: </br>
      <input type="email" name="email"></br>
      Телефон: </br>
      <input type="text" name="phone"></br>
      Имя: </br>
      <input type="text" name="name"></br>
      <input type="button" id="send" value="Отправить">
      <div id="result"></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: В ошибке показывает html файл - <!DOCTYPE html> - часть. *

Comment: на момент каких изменений вы начали ловить в консоль ошибку?

Comment: Можно сказать, почти сразу, как закончил писать ajax код.